# Is it possible to define a RoundedRectangle with some properties as a variable for later usage in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to reuse a RoundedRectangle that has certain properties multiple times in my View. Is defining it as a variable possible?

And while my code is pretty much like this

```
Struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
      
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24)
                        .frame(width: 180, height: 240)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.white))

      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24)
                        .frame(width: 180, height: 240)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.white))

      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24)
                        .frame(width: 180, height: 240)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.white))
   }
}
```

I'd want to do something like this

```
Struct ContentView: View {

   let basicPanel = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24)
                        .frame(width: 180, height: 240)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.white))

   var body: some View {
      basicPanel
      basicPanel
      basicPanel
   }
}
```

Sincerely sorry if the question is written terribly, It's my first question on StackOverflow ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just add type declaration `some View` for variable, like

```
let basicPanel: some View = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24)
                    .frame(width: 180, height: 240)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.white))
```

Comment: This should be declared inside the the main 
ContentView: View{}

but outside the 
var body: some View{}

Am i right?

Comment: In general depends on your preference, but can be in any. If outside, it will be instantiated once per created view, in body will be created on every render.